# how to increment macro in C++?

Tags: c++

I have to calculate the number of times a method is called. So I have a macro A initially set to 0. Can I increment it with my particular method like A++ and return it in the main method.Or how would I use the **COUNTER** macro.

Comment: Are you sure you want to use a macro? Even a global variable would be better.

Comment: I recommend setting a global variable like beta said, macro isn't necessary for this kind of stuff.

Comment: It can't be done with macros!

Comment: macro is not a variable, how can it store values? for counting a static local variable is enough

Answer (score 0):

> I have a macro A initially set to 0. Can I increment it with my particular method like A++ ?

No ++ needs a lvalue, you cannot do 0++, as `A` will be replaced as its value after per-processing.

Why not simply make it as global, or use call by reference ?

Comment: I have no idea about c++ programming. how do i make a global reference

Comment: @user2852227: Get [a decent C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list?rq=1).

Answer (score 0):

A macro is only processed by the preprocessor, which is only run at compilation and has no knowledge of how many times a function is actually called. As Beta said, you can use a variable to store this count, but even that needs to be done carefully if you have multiple threads calling the method.